# ADB immersive mode and wm overscan commands no longer work on Android 11

Tags: adb, updates, android-11, immersive-mode

I upgraded to Android 11 without knowing that it broke compatibility with existing immersive mode and window manger overscan adb commands. Are there new alternatives to these commands in adb now? I was specifically using:

`adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,-136 (reset: 0,0,0,0)`

`adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.status=*`

For reference I'm running GrapheneOS on build number RP1A.200720.009.2020.09.25.00 on a Pixel 3 with Android 11 on Kernel version 4.9.223.

Comment: There was recently [a self-deleted question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229692) stating the same issue about Android 11 and ADB on `immersive.status`, though there's no comment nor answer.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yeah I saw that when attempting to research a solution. I was not the poster of that question though, I decided to post partly to "replace" that deleted question.